# custom post type search by reference id

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have a custom content type of `tab_content` with a relationship to a `page`.

In my current script I have the *id* of a `page` and I want to do a query that will list all the children of type `tab_content` that have the relationship of a `page` with the specified id.

All I have so far is:

```
new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'tab_content'));
```

How do I tell the query that the custom field `parent` needs to be something like `80`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `post_parent` paramter or WP_Query ex:

```
new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'tab_content',
    'post_parent' => 80
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually using a relation from the `custom post type` plugin.

I had to reference a custom field which gave me the whole reference post.

`get_custom_field('tab_content_relationship');` and viola.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to do what you want with WP_Query is to use two queries:

1. Get the list of IDs of `tab_content` posts associated with a page.
2. Query for children of those IDs.

You could use `get_posts()` for the first query if you want, but that's all I can think of.